# Spree Commerce Syntax Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

I really don't think there is a syntax issue, I think it might be a version issue, though, what does this look like to y'all? Note, this only happens in production environment. I'm using passenger (since it's Rails 3 and I don't like to use beta gems in production):

Gem Version: 1.8.23
Rails Version: 3.2.11
Ruby Version: 1.9.3p374 ( I upgraded it thinking it would help, was 1.8.7 I think before )

```
# rails s -e production
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.11 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `polyglot_original_require': /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/spree_api-1.3.1/app/controllers/spree/api/product_properties_controller.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected '.' (SyntaxError)
      .page(params[:page]).per(params[:per_page])
       ^
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `eager_load!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `eager_load!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise/controllers/url_helpers.rb:47:in `to_proc'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `all'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:434:in `eager_load!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/$user/rails_apps/store/config/environment.rb:5
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `polyglot_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /home/$user/rails_apps/store/config.ru:3
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /home/$user/rails_apps/store/config.ru:0:in `new'
    from /home/$user/rails_apps/store/config.ru:0
```

If more info is needed, please let me know and I can send any info requested (within reason of course).

Edit addition:

I fixed the wayward "." but see this now:

```
# rails s -e production
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.11 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `polyglot_original_require': /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/spree_api-1.3.1/app/controllers/spree/api/v1/base_controller.rb:68: odd number list for Hash (SyntaxError)
      render :text => { exception: exception.message }.to_json,
                                  ^
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/spree_api-1.3.1/app/controllers/spree/api/v1/base_controller.rb:68: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
      render :text => { exception: exception.message }.to_json,
                                  ^
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/spree_api-1.3.1/app/controllers/spree/api/v1/base_controller.rb:68: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting kEND
      render :text => { exception: exception.message }.to_json,
                                                      ^
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/spree_api-1.3.1/app/controllers/spree/api/v1/base_controller.rb:69: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.'
             :status => 422 and return
                       ^
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `eager_load!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `eager_load!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise/controllers/url_helpers.rb:47:in `to_proc'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `all'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:434:in `eager_load!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/jackal/rails_apps/store/config/environment.rb:5
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `polyglot_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /home/jackal/rails_apps/store/config.ru:3
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /home/jackal/rails_apps/store/config.ru:0:in `new'
    from /home/jackal/rails_apps/store/config.ru:0
```

Comment: Oh, here is the area around line 11:

    def index
        @product_properties = @product.product_properties.ransack(params[:q]).result +
              .page(params[:page]).per(params[:per_page])
            respond_with(@product_properties)
          end

Comment: We'd need to see your code (click "Edit" to add it to your question).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using Ruby 1.8 (based on `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/` in the path), but the hash syntax in the `render :text => { exception: exception.message }.to_json` is Ruby 1.9 only.

In Ruby 1.9, you can say: `h = {key: 1}`
In Ruby 1.8, you must use `h = {:key => 1}`

Answer (score 0):

The wayward "`.`" is at the beginning of this

`.page(params[:page]).per(params[:per_page])`

in the line

`@product_properties = @product.product_properties.ransack(params[:q]).result + .page(params[:page]).per(params[:per_page])`

just like it says at the beginning of the error message.

Comment: This is what I was afraid of. Obviously, as the error message states, this is a syntax error -- but, is it a syntax error for a version of Ruby I am not using?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm pretty sure it's a syntax error in the Ruby language generally, and won't matter which version.

Comment: I edited my original post, couldn't add it here as a comment.